# Custom Android Authenticator

Tags: android

I have some android apps, so i want to build a custom authenticator for these apps.
I implement a custom authenticator like this  [article](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/). It work fine, but as article's author said " First in, first served", the first installed app’s authenticator will be called for both apps when an auth-token will be requested. So for second app, i can't custom login or logout request.

Any one meet this problem before, can give me some idea.

Thanks !